# MySQL where clause in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How to pass id in where clause using `node.js` and `MySQL`？

**Viewer.jsx**

```
async function redeem(cid) {
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/getDetailsFromCid/${cid}').then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
    .then(posts => {
      console.log("posts", posts)    

    })
    .then((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

**index.js**

```
app.get("/api/getDetailsFromCid/:cid", (req, res) => {
    const cid = req.params.cid;
    db.query("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE cid = ?", [cid],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            res.send(result)
        });
});
```

**Error**

```
Viewer.jsx:19          GET http://localhost:4000/getDetailsFromCid/$%7Bcid%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `` not ''

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/getDetailsFromCid/${cid}`)
```

Comment: still same error

Comment: have you tried appending `api`